# Simulink From block accepting values from matlab code

Tags: matlab, simulink, pwm

I have the following Simulink model : DC/AC Half-Bridge Inverter, that uses an **PWM block** (inside the Green Frame) to generate the switching signals to the IGBTs, The **From block** (inside the Red frame) accepts a signal from the PWM using the Goto block, then passes it as output to the IGBTs.

[image: Schema]

I'm trying to build a custom PWM using Matlab code :

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
t=0:0.001:1;
s=sawtooth(2*pi*10*t+pi);
m=0.75*sin(2*pi*1*t);
n=length(s);
for i=1:n
    if (m(i)>=s(i))
        pwm(i)=1;
    elseif (m(i)<=s(i))
        pwm(i)=0;
    end
end
plot(t,pwm,'-g',t,m,'--r',t,s,'--b');
grid on;
ylabel('Amplitude');
xlabel('Time index');
title('PWM Wave');
axis([0 1 -1.5 1.5]);
```

Here is the result of the plot :

[image]

**My Question :**

I know that **t** contains the time values and **pwm** contains the pwm values, So i want to know how to **"somehow"** redirect those Data from the Matlab code, through the From Block into the IGBTs so i can use them as switching signal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest is to just use a [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block as a direct replacement for the `PWM Generator (2 Pulses)` block.

Run your MATLAB code to define the variables in the MATLAB Workspace, and (assuming your `G1_1` and `G2_1` signals are the negation of each other) use `[t(:) pwm(:) ~pwm(:)]` as the block's Data parameter.

Note also, that you don't need the loop in your code:

```
pwm = (m >= s);
```

or if you need them to be doubles rather than logical then

```
pwm = double(m >= s);
```

Comment: using From Workspace actually worked perfectly, thank you so much